# Replacement for Array#nitems in Ruby 1.9?

Tags: ruby, arrays

Ruby 1.8 had a method `nitems` for arrays.  This seems to be gone from Ruby 1.9. Is there a replacement for it in 1.9?

Answer (score 8):

it's been deleted from Ruby 1.9

you can use this instead:

```
array = [nil, 2, "a", nil, 'b', nil]
array.count{|x| !x.nil?}
 => 3
```

or you can re-define it yourself, if your Ruby version doesn't have it anymore:

```
if ! Array.method_defined?(:nitems)
  class Array
    def nitems
      count{|x| !x.nil?}
    end
  end
end


a = [nil, 2, "a", nil, 'b', nil]
a.nitems
 => 3
```

Comment: yes, that will work too, but it will create a new array instance as the result of `compact`

Comment: `unless` is better than `if !`